# Jest manual mock not getting executed for Higher Order Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to Jest, I am trying to mock my context HOC function to test my component
Here is my folder structure

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiYlj.png)

Basically I am trying to mock the homeContext.js file which is being used by my HomeScreen component. As per the docs I have created a `__mocks__` folder under the contexts folder and created a `homeContext.js` file

Here are the contents of the files:

`/contexts/__mocks__/homeContext.js`

```
const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
console.log('Mocking');
return {
  withHomeContext: jest.fn(() => {}),
 };
});

module.exports = mock;
```

`contexts/homeContext.js`

```
export const withHomeContext = ChildComponent => props => {
console.log('Not Hitting');
  return (
    <HomeContext.Consumer>
      {context => <ChildComponent {...props} homeContext={context} />}
    </HomeContext.Consumer>
  );
};
```

Here is how I am trying to use it in my `scenes/home/index.test.js`

```
jest.mock('../../contexts/homeContext');
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import HomeScreen from './index';

describe('<HomeScreen /> renders', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<HomeScreen />);
    expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
  });
})
```

This is how the component which I am testing uses it

```
import * as React from 'react';

//Context
import {withHomeContext} from '../../contexts/homeContext';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      relatedItems: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
     //Some render logic
  }
}

export default withHomeContext(HomeScreen);
```

Please help me why my `__mocks__/homeContext.js` never gets hit, it is hitting the actual file, which console logs ('Not Hitting')